# HTML entity decoding in Java: apostrophe

Tags: java, html, apache-commons, decoding

I have to decode, using Java, HTML strings which contain the following entities: "&#39" and "&apos".
I'm using [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), but it doesn't decode those two entities, so, I'm currently doing as follows, but I'm looking for the fastest way to do what I want.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class StringUtil {

        public static String decodeHTMLString(String s) {
            return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml((s.replace("&amp;#39;", "`").replace("&apos;", "'")));
        }

}
```

I searched for older questions, but none seems to answer my question.

Comment: heh, don't forget to include "smart quotes" in that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I think I'll find many entities not included in standard HTML. The problem, however, is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i would imagine that part of the problem is that one of your entities is double encoded: "`&amp;#39;`".  That will not be turned into an apostrophe by any decoder.

As for "`&apos;`", apparently that one is not +technically+ part of the html entity set.

Comment: mmm... about the first point, you're right, it's double encoded.
For the other one, ok, &apos; it's not part of standard HTML, but I need to translate it and I'd like to know if there are faster ways to translate it than mine